# How to prevent the Fields plugin from displaying the hasMany fields

Tags: grails

I googled couple hours but didn't find the answer.  I have an Author who hasMany Book.

```
Class Author {
   String name
   static hasMany = [books: Book]
}
```

The <f:all> tag in the edit.gsp view will display all the properties from the Author **and** list all the **Book** and a **Add Book** button at the bottom of the page.

I want the <f:all> tag to display only the properties from the Author.  I don't want it to display the list of books or the Add Book button.

Where and what can I type to set the <f:all> tag from only displaying the actual properties from the Author domain?

Comment: "I googled couple hours but didn't find the answer." - Does the `except` attribute described at https://grails-fields-plugin.github.io/grails-fields/latest/ref/Tags/all.html help?

Comment: No, `except` only works for the actual property of the Author class.  The hasMang `books` is not the property of the Author class.  I tried this already.